# How to go about creating a custom data export plugin from Maya (or similar) to Unreal Engine?

Tags: c++, plugins, maya, unreal-engine4, game-development

I'm trying to get into game development as a tools programmer and to get some hands on experience I was told I should try to create a custom data export plugin for Maya/Max to Unreal. I'm not sure how to go about starting this project and google searches haven't been helpful or productive.
I have experience in C++ and I'm going through tutorials for Unreal Engine now. I haven't downloaded Maya because I'm not a student anymore so I can't get the free version and I want to make the most out of the free 30-day trial when I do download it.
Does anyone have any suggestions on where to start with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The maya devKit contains a lot of examples from command plugins up to Viewport renderers. And as much as I know there is an exporter as well. So you could download it and have a look at the example projects there.

If I'm not completele mistaken, you can use Maya in batch mode withou a license, at least it was the case for a long time. So you could use it for 30 days and after that period, you can try to start it in batch mode and execute your stuff even if it is a bit tricky because you do not have visual feedback.

And to be honest if you search for a "maya api exporter" you should get some decent results. e.g. the very first result here is "Maya API - Writing a plugin exporter".